# Joining two tables without JPQL

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have to MySQL tables TICKET-is the parent and USER-is the child, in a many-to-one relationship.

```
=TICKET=
PK(ID)
summary
message
FK(user_id) references USER(user_id)

=USER=
PK(ID)
email
password
```

And the JPA entities

```
@Entity 
class TICKET {
    @Id
    private Integer ID;
    private String summary;
    private String message;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user")
    private USER user;
}

@Entity
class USER {
    @Id
    private Integer ID;
    private String email;
    private String password;
}
```

If i make a query to get a ticket by ID it will return also the user information (USER.ID, USER.email, USER.password) which is not good.

```
ticketsCrudRepository.findById(ticketId);
```

What i want is to get a table that looks like this:

```
TICKET.ID | summary | message | USER.email
```

I know how to do it in MySQL but JPA it's to much for me. I don't want to use JPQL or native query language.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

When you fetch a Ticket you also get a User since `@ManyToOne` by default has `FetchType.EAGER`.  You can change this by changing the anotation to `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)`

To do the search you chould try somethig like

```
public List<Object[]> getTikcetsForUser(final User user) {
   String hql = "select t.id, t.summary, t.message, u.email "
                + "from Tikcet t, User u "
                + "where ticket.user = :user";

   Query<Object[]> query = getSession().createQuery(hql, Object[].class);
   query.setParameter("user", user);
   return query.getResultList();
}
```

The returned List will contain arrays with 4 fields (t.id, t.summary, t.message, u.email).

Please let me know if you find this useful.

:)

Comment: I already knew that possibility and i was hoping for something that will not require me to type the SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

The solution i was looking for was Spring Data JPA Projections. They can be interfaces or classes with getters that match the columns you want to get from the database. For detailed informations check the [Spring Framework documentation here.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections)

Answer (score 0):

Using Spring Data Projections is one option, but you will at some point run into the limitations it has. If you reach that point, you can look into [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(TICKET.class)
public interface TicketDto {
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();
    String getName();
    UserDto getUser();

    @EntityView(USER.class)
    interface UserDto {
        @IdMapping
        Long getId();
        String getEmail();
    }
}
```

Or even simpler in your case

```
@EntityView(TICKET.class)
public interface TicketDto {
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();
    String getName();
    @Mapping("user.email")
    String getUserEmail();
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`TicketDto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, TicketDto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features